# Character encoding CP037

Tags: objective-c, ios, character-encoding

Am converting an application from java to objective-c and have run into an issue around character encoding.

In the java code the statement am trying to convert is:

```
byte[] instructions = input.getBytes("CP037");
```

I was hoping to do the following in objective-c:

```
 const char *instructions = [input CP037];
```

However "CP037" doesn't exist as an encoding, does anyone know how to overcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got there in the end:

```
 NSString *stringThatNeedsToBeEncoded = @"randomString";  
 CFDataRef encodedStringAsCFData = CFStringCreateExternalRepresentation(CFAllocatorGetDefault(), (CFStringRef)stringThatNeedsToBeEncoded, kCFStringEncodingEBCDIC_CP037, 0); 

 CFIndex bufferLength = CFDataGetLength(encodedStringAsCFData);  
 UInt8 *buffer = malloc(bufferLength);  
 CFDataGetBytes(encodedStringAsCFData, CFRangeMake(0, CFDataGetLength(encodedStringAsCFData)), buffer);
```